# I can't bind WPF DataGrid to ADO.NET DataView

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I can't bind WPF DataGrid to ADO.NET DataView and I don't know what can I do with it. I do the following in MainWindow class:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private DataSet _ds;
    /// <summary>
    ///This property is a data source for DataGrid.
    /// </summary>
    public DataView GridData { get { return _ds.Tables[0].DefaultView; } }

    /// <summary>
    /// Do fetching all records from table called DrugHandbook in database.
    /// </summary>
    public static void SelectAllRecordsFromDrugHandbook()
    {
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
        {
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("Select_All_Records_From_DrugHandbook", connection);
            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
            _ds = new DataSet();
            adapter.Fill(_ds);
        }
    }
}
```

Then in XAML I wrote the following:

```
<Window x:Class="ClientApp.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="DrugHandbook" Height="350" Width="525" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">
    <Grid>
. . . . . . . . . . . . . .

        <DataGrid Name="dgDrugs" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" ItemsSource="{Binding 
Path=GridData, Mode=OneWay}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False" 
CanUserDeleteRows="False" CanUserReorderColumns="False" CanUserResizeColumns="False" 
CanUserResizeRows="False" CanUserSortColumns="False" SelectionMode="Single">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Price" Binding="{Binding Path=Price}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Form of Pack" Binding="{Binding Path=Pack}"/>
                <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="By Prescription" Binding="{Binding
 Path=Prescription}"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>

. . . . . . . . . . . . . .  
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Here is script for DrugHandbook database table. "DrugId" field is the primary key.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DrugHandbook](
    [DrugId] [uniqueidentifier] ROWGUIDCOL  NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [Price] [money] NULL,
    [Pack] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [Prescription] [bit] NULL,
    )
```

And after _ds DataSet filled by the data, this data is not shown in the dgDrugs DataGrid. _ds DataSet is filled by data successfully, I checked it in debug mode. What I'm doing wrong here? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the following Msdn link, it discusses exactly what you are trying to achieve.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752057(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752057%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Pay close attention to the Datacontext assignment(the dataset), the item template (defines the way data appears in the datagrid), and the itemssource
(The table name).

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks shahar, but unfortunately your answer doesn't help me.I bag your pardon. My question remains urgent and actual for me.

Comment: I'm not in need of links to forums or CodeProject here. Please show me here how I must correct my code to make binding work correctly. Please.